# Cert already in hash table exception

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, x509certificate, embedded-ruby

I am using chef dk version 12 and i have done basic setup and uploaded many cookbooks , currently i am using remote_directory in my default.rb 
What i have observed is whenever there are too many files /hierarchy in the directory the upload fails with the below exception :-

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: xyz.com - SSL_write: cert already in hash table
ERROR: Could not establish a secure connection to the server.
Use `knife ssl check` to troubleshoot your SSL configuration.
If your Chef Server uses a self-signed certificate, you can use
`knife ssl fetch` to make knife trust the server's certificates. 
Original Exception: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_write: cert already in hash table
```

As mentioned earlier connection to server isnt a problem it happens only when there are too many files/the hierarchy is more . 
Can you please suggest what i can do? I have tried searching online for solutions but failed to get a solution

I have checked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263121/opensslx509storeerror-cert-already-in-hash-table) but it doesnt solve my problem
Chef uses embedded ruby and openssl for people not working with chef

Some updates on suggestion of [tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai), 
The exceptions have changed since adding the option of `--concurrency 1` ,
Initially i had received, 
`INFO: HTTP Request Returned 403 Forbidden:ERROR: Failed to upload filepath\file (7a81e65b51f0d514ec645da49de6417d) to example.com:443/bookshelf/… 3088476d373416dfbaf187590b5d5687210a75&Expires=1435139052&Signature=SP/70MZP4C2U‌​dUd9%2B5Ct1jEV1EQ%3D : 403 "Forbidden" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>`

Then yesterday it has changed to 
`INFO: HTTP Request Returned 413 Request Entity Too Large: error
ERROR: Request Entity Too Large 
Response: JSON must be no more than 1000000 bytes.`

Should i decrease the number of files or is there any other option?

`Knife --version` results in Chef: 12.3.0

Comment: Did you tried `knife ssl check`/`knife ssl fetch` as suggested?

Comment: Yes i have already done that as said in the post , the connection is established but fails on more hierarchial directory structure or many files,the ouput for the same is:- Connecting to host xyz:443
Successfully verified certificates from `xyz.com'

Comment: may you try with option `--concurrency 1` (the default is 10) ? I suspect a race condition between many threads uploading files. I think there's a bug about it that was fixed. If it works with 1, try increasing until it errors again.

Comment: Hi i tried with concurrency as 1 it took way too long but returned this :INFO: HTTP Request Returned 403 Forbidden:
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ContentLengthMismatch: Response body length 0 does not match HTTP Content-Length header 206. Will try to hit once more , had tried with 5 and 2 both times got certificate error again

Comment: I tied again now its giving the below exception :- INFO: HTTP Request Returned 403 Forbidden:ERROR: Failed to upload filepath\file (7a81e65b51f0d514ec645da49de6417d) to https://example.com:443/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-7a81e65b51f0d514ec645da49de6417d?AWSAccessKeyId=6d
3088476d373416dfbaf187590b5d5687210a75&Expires=1435139052&Signature=SP/70MZP4C2UdUd9%2B5Ct1jEV1EQ%3D : 403 "Forbidden"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABZtiAAIfLWIAAHNh</R

Comment: Reading on a forum i had increased the erchef value of s3_ssl_ttl from 900 to 7200 for Response body length 0 error

Comment: Also the access denied error came with ERROR: You authenticated successfully to https://example.com:443 as node but you are not authorized for this action
Response:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>g2gCZAATYm9va3NoZWxmQDEyNy4wLjAuMWgDYgAABZtiAAIfLWIAAHNh
</RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>

Comment: @Raul Ping people with @ in comments (so there's a notification) and edit your question to include the new messages, comments are bad to format and unreadable

Comment: So the problem with little concurency is that the Auth_key for the request time out (15 mins max). Could confirm the knife version with `knife --version` ? (should be `Chef : xx.yy.z`)

Answer (score 1):

> Should i decrease the number of files or is there any other option?

Ususally the files inside a cookbook are not intended to be too large and too numerous, if you got a lot of files to ditribute it's a sign you should change the way you distribute thoose files.

One option could be to make a tarball, but this makes harder to manage the deleted files.

Another option if you're on an internal chef-server is to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020549/3627607) and change the `client_max_body_size 2M;` value for nginx but I can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out , as far as creating tarball goes i cannot update a file individually from the same cookbook if there is a minor change , will have to create tarball again etc.

Comment: @Raul that's where continuous integration (CI) come in place, building an artifact from files when changed, and deploying a new artifact to servers (using jenkins and a repo like nexus or artifactory for exemple)

Comment: I changed in http section `client_max_body_size 2M;` and restarted the nginx service but it didnt help as you already said you can't guarantee it will work i will go ahead with reducing the size of directories, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and i ran `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` on chef server then tried uploading cookbook again and all started working fine again