# what are the side effects of disabling ohai 'passwd' plugin

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

I have couple of nodes where i face '413 "Request Entity Too Large" error'. After googling, I found that we need to disable the 'passwd' ohai plugin to reduce the node data size which is being saved to Chef server - Referring to:  [Opscode Chef Request entity too large registering a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454765/opscode-chef-request-entity-too-large-registering-a-node)
 Just wanted to know, if there will be any side effect, if we disable the 'passwd' ohai plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side effect is that `node['etc']['passwd']` wont' be populated.